# How to remotely save subsite as a template with powershell on Project Server 2019 on-prem

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-on-prem, project-server

I have a project subsite on my Project Server 2019 on-prem, which I want to save as a template to make it a standard for all projects that will be created.
Via my Browser the process is very straight forward, but I need to create the template automatically as part of the deployment process. So far I have not found a way to do this remotely.

It there a way to remotely save a site as a template? If yes, how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

I would use PnP-PowerShell to automate the provisioning of sites. You should look into the, `Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate` and `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate` commands.

They export an xml file of all of the features of a Site which can then be re-applied onto other sites to turn them into the original template.